# Assembly What happens when you move multiple numbers into a register?

Tags: assembly

I have this assembly code:

```
foo:
    pushl %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp
    pushl %edi
    pushl %esi
    pushl %ebx
    sub $0x12c, %esp
    movl $0x1, (%esp)
    movl $0x2, 0x4(%esp)
    movl $0x3, 0x8(%esp)
    movl $0x4, 0xc(%esp)
```

I am trying to find the difference between the value of %esp at the end of the code, and the location of the saved return address (%ebp ?). Basically, I'm trying to understand what is happening to %esp. I know move puts a value/ overwrites a value into a register, and I *think* that putting a number before a register defines that place in the register. So, does

```
    movl $0x1, (%esp)
    movl $0x2, 0x4(%esp)
    movl $0x3, 0x8(%esp)
    movl $0x4, 0xc(%esp)
```

put 1 into the first slot of %esp, 2 into the 4th slot of %esp, 3 into the 8th slot of %esp, and 4 into the c (12th) slot of %esp??? Would this result in 100200030004?

Also, I don't really understand the 
`sub $0x12c, %esp`,
I thought that you had to put the register before the number to subtract, or am I wrong? I dont see how you could subtract 12c (300) from %esp.

As far as I understand, the non "sub" and "mov" lines aren't really relevant.

I am extremely new to assembly, but I have spent a ton of time on this problem, and am still finding it difficult to understand what it does. Could someone please help me?

Comment: *"I dont see how you could subtract 12c (300) from %esp."* ... well, that sounds ok to me, you take the current `esp` value, subtract `0x12c` from it, and store result into `esp`. Other way around (subtracting `esp` from immediate `0x12c`) makes no sense, and does not exist on x86 CPU. Only `sub r32,imm32` is valid (that definition is in Intel syntax, where destination is first, in your sources you are using gas (AT&T) syntax, which has it in reversed order and is annoying for my eyes).

Comment: Registers don't have "slots", and this isn't moving values into registers at all. Rather, it is storing values into *memory* – specifically the stack, which you can tell because it's using `esp` (the stack pointer) as the base.

Comment: the (parenthesis) implies register indirect the number before is an offset so 0x5(esp) means take the value in esp add 5 to it then use that as an address

Comment: So are you learning assembly programming by just looking at program code? Don't you have a textbook to rely on?

Comment: @SepRoland No, unfortunately. I am practicing CTF and this is one of the problems... I was thrown headfirst into assembly ;_;

Comment: @kloc.b for instruction reference using google "x86 instruction <instruction_name>" usually goes to one of sites similar to this one: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/  ... but if you are completely unprepared and didn't study anything about assembly, it may be still too tough, you should take some assembly course/lessons first, to have some idea what are registers, bits, bytes, memory, etc.. (practicing "capture the flag"? ... yeah, I did that too, back in Quake 2 days...)

Answer (score 4):

First answer to your title question: register is N bits storage on the CPU chip, by "moving a value" into register you set up all its bits to particular state (0/1). If you "move multiple numbers" into register, each assignment overwrites the whole register, i.e. the last assigned value is in the register, the previous ones are lost.

```
    ...
    movl $0x1, (%esp)
    movl $0x2, 0x4(%esp)
    movl $0x3, 0x8(%esp)
    movl $0x4, 0xc(%esp)
```

This does not move anything into register.

This is in Intel syntax (check the AT&T syntax if you are not sure, how it works, it's quite tricky, as for example the mere existence of `$` ahead of numeric value does change significantly the meaning of instruction, with `$` it's immediate value, without it is memory address to be accessed... but accessing memory through register needs parentheses, offsets are outside, multipliers of index register are inside ... generally very hard to read for me, Intel syntax is a bit more "human" IMO):

```
    mov [esp],dword 1
    mov [esp+4],dword 2
    mov [esp+8],dword 3
    mov [esp+12],dword 4
```

Which means that 32-bit values (1, 2, 3, 4) are stored into 16 bytes of memory starting at address "current value stored in register `esp`".

So if `esp` was for example `0x8F001000` before this code, and memory there was:

```
address    byte values (content)
0x8F001000 CC CC CC CC DE AD DE AD CC CC CC CC DE AD DE AD
0x8F001010 AA BB CC CC 00 11 DE AD AA BB CC CC 00 11 DE AD
```

Then after running that piece of code the memory content will change to:

```
address    byte values (content)
0x8F001000 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
0x8F001010 AA BB CC CC 00 11 DE AD AA BB CC CC 00 11 DE AD
```

The value in `esp` will remain intact, still `0x8F001000`.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I don't quite understand.
the exact question I have is 
"Can you find the difference between the value of esp at the end of the code, and the location of the saved return address? Assume a 32 bit system. Submit the answer as a hexidecimal number, with no extraneous 0s. For example, the decimal number 2015 would be submitted as 0x7df, not 0x000007df"
So you're saying that esp *doesn't* change? Submitting that doesn't work. I am so sorry to bother you any more, but I was literally just thrown this problem, and it would ease my mind very much to know the correct answer.

Comment: @kloc.b The `movl $0x2, 0x4(%esp)` does not change `esp`. There are of course many different instructions changing it (including `call` and `ret` (and `push` obviously, but you know how `push/pop` works?!)), just check the instruction reference guide for details over every instruction (but you have to understand first the argument syntax, so you can pick the correct variant of instruction in the description, as most of the detail docs are in Intel syntax, i.e. `mov [esp+4],dword 2` in this case.